# Excel row increment formula

Tags: excel, row, formula

Can someone help me with excel about the formula row increment.
I have a sheet (I6)Column and im copying a data on another sheet (H138)Row,
what i need to do is copy I6 column down (I7,I8,I9) that will follow and have the data on the other sheet which is (I138,J138,K138).

The current formula the excel giving me is (H139,H140,H141).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [OFFSET function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) using [ROW](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) to increment the column as you fill down.

```
=offset('Other Sheet'!G$138, 0, row(1:1))
```

Comment: ive used your answer, but when i fill down it doesnt copy the next row (I138,J138,K138)

Comment: Sorry; you needed to lock the row number on G138 like G$138.